# How can I sort the featured blog posts in the top of the list in Octobercms

Tags: laravel, octobercms, octobercms-backend

My request is simple. I want to keep my blog list ordered by `created_at DESC` but I want also to show the featured posts in top.

Let's say that I have 4 categories : Gold, Silver, Bronze and Other ...

I want to display the Gold posts first.

Then the Silver posts.

Followed by the Bronze posts.

And finally the others.

All of them should be ordered by `created_at DESC`.

1. Is there a feature out of the box to do that ?
2. Or should I create a new plugin to extend Blog with this feature ?

What do you think ?

Comment: @CaddyDZ, Is the desired behavior and the specific problem here are not clear ? I'm not sure if this feature is covered by the CMS or should be implemented in a new Plugin. I even gave an example .. so ... !

Comment: You're asking for a feature implementation with no starting point whatsoever, please edit your question and show us what you have tried so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are using the Rainlab Blog plugin. There are numerous ways to solve this and I don't think there is an official "way". Here are some examples that you will have to fit for your own code.

1. Solution with Twig. Twig has a sort filter which you can pass in an
   arrow function, [check
   here](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/sort.html). Then you
   can do if statements to display gold to bronze.

   ```
   {% for blog in blogs|sort((a, b) => a.created_at <=> b.created_at) %}
   {% if blog.category == Gold %}{{ blog }}{% endif %}
   {% endfor %}
   ```
2. Adhoc [CMS
   Page](https://octobercms.com/docs/cms/themes#php-section). Instead
   of using the rain blag component you can use the plugin in the PHP
   Code to the page/layout/partial. This is where give you the ability
   to work with the model to organize it the way you want to. Here I am
   using OctoberCMS [querying
   features](https://octobercms.com/docs/database/relations#querying-existence).

   ```
   use Rainlab\Blog\Models\Post;

   public function onStart() {
       $this['golds'] = Post::whereHas('categories', function ($query) {
           $query->where('name', 'Gold');
       })->get()->sortBy('create_at');
   }
   ```
3. Third way and the way I recommend is to build your own plugin which
   can either extend or filter the blogs posts like how I did in the
   CMS Page example. [Read the documentation here](https://octobercms.com/docs/plugin/registration).

One side note that if you click into the `{% component 'something' %}` you can expand the htm template.

[image]

Comment: So helpful. This is what I was looking for. Thank you.